# programatically putting text at Chrome console prompt

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I defined a function that I run using Chrome console.
So I would type `my_function()` then hit `enter` to call my function.

Sometimes I need to call my function many times (the exact number is unknown), so I'll repeat `up` `enter` to repeatedly call my function.

I was wondering if I can let my function write `my_function()` at the prompt after it's execution, so that I'll just need to keep hitting `enter` to call my function however many times I want?

I don't know much about JavaScript, so my approach could be totally wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing first I am ok with the first solution. But in case you really want to stay in the chrome devtool why not using [snippets](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/snippets) they are the perfect tool for what you what:

-Go to the snippet pane. Write a snippet of your function.

-Call it.

-Keep running it by clicking or use Control+Enter or Command+Enter.

Another solution can be stackoverflow site. Go to any question. your for example in the answer part click on javascript/html/css snippet and do your thing

Comment: I like this solution more because I can use it right away without learning how to use userscript or putting a button on the webpage.

Comment: For sure. I am glad It helps.

Answer (score 3):

I'd insert a button into the document instead, then click that button as needed:

```
const button = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('button'));
button.textContent = 'click me';
button.addEventListener('click', my_function);
```

If you want to be able to do this sort of thing automatically (have the button inserted on pageload without having to type the code into the console yourself every time), put it into [a userscript](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en).